# How to write a CASE statement that is inclusive of all conditions?

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have a case statement like:

```sql
case
    when invoice_net_amount <= 50 then '1. <= 50'
    when invoice_net_amount > 50 then '2. > 50'
    when invoice_net_amount > 250 then '3. > 250'
    when invoice_net_amount > 500 then '4. > 500'
end as user_revenue_tier
```

The problem is that all users fall in the first two buckets. I would like users with `invoice_net_amount > 50` to show in `buckets` `2`, `3`, and `4` instead of just `2`.

Is there a way to do this? I am using Snowflake if that matters.

Comment: Only use < all the way.

Comment: `case` _expression_.

Comment: In the first 'when' you test <=50, so in the second one you don't need to test for >50

Answer (score 2):

You need to phrase the conditions like this:

```
(case when invoice_net_amount <= 50  then '1. <= 50'
      when invoice_net_amount <= 250 then '2. > 50'
      when invoice_net_amount <= 500 then '3. > 250'
      else '4. > 500'
 end) as user_revenue_tier
```

`case` expressions stop at the first matching condition.  So, a value of 1000 matches `> 50`, so it goes to the second condition.  As phrased in this answer, it falls through to the `else`.

Answer (score 0):

CASE expression is evaluated based on order of conditions and first match "wins":

```
case   
    when invoice_net_amount > 500 then '4. > 500'
    when invoice_net_amount > 250 then '3. > 250'
    when invoice_net_amount > 50  then '2. > 50'
    when invoice_net_amount <= 50 then '1. <= 50'
end as user_revenue_tier
```

By swapping the order you will get desired results.